# Apple Sign In stacks in PHP Function for Capacitor 4

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am having a problem with my Sign In Apple function on Capacitor 4.
[image]

1. The dialog to give the password for the Apple Id open just fine but when it call the php function it stucks like the photo i uploaded.
2. I have many function in PHP that work just fine

The error it give is for my backend PHP function

```
  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
    ERROR
HttpErrorResponse

error: null

headers: HttpHeaders

lazyInit: function()

arguments: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.

caller: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.

length: 0

name: ""

Function Prototype

lazyUpdate: null

normalizedNames: Map {} (0)

HttpHeaders Prototype

message: "Http failure response for https://project.com/project_api/api/sign_in_with_apple: 500 OK"

name: "HttpErrorResponse"

ok: false

status: 500

statusText: "OK"

url: "https://project.com/project_api/api/sign_in_with_apple"
```

and the network error

```
    Summary
URL: https://project.com/project_api/api/sign_in_with_apple
Status: 500
Source: Network
Address: 185.35.33.55:553
Initiator: 
zone.js:3454


Request
:method: POST
:scheme: https
:authority: project.com
:path: /project_api/api/sign_in_with_apple
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: capacitor://localhost
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: rovespier.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148
Content-Length: 1074
Accept-Language: el-GR,el;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive

Response
:status: 500
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9ca0e5311a0376ade70056525d9a765f; path=/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2023 09:20:35 GMT
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Server: nginx

Request Data
MIME Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
login_data[response][identityToken]: eyJraWQiOiJmaDZCczhDIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiY29tLnJvdmVzcGllci5tb2JpbGUiLCJleHAiOjE2NzUxNTY4MzQsImlhdCI6MTY3NTA3MDQzNCwic3ViIjoiMDAwNjc0LjZiMDUzYzSI6Im5vbmNlIiwiY19oYXNoIjoiZUY2WEdNRDhtYzViT3o0U0JVQnF5QSIsImVtYWlsIjoic2ltb25pb2FubmlkZXNAaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6InRydWUiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2NzUwNzA0MzQsIm5vbmNlX3N1cHBvcnRlZCI6dHJ1ZX0.bvXBlch8O-H690PsIFNZpJqauCcdozuZggt0I1nGY0PHQ075OSHKYlUXvsY_aOTIEzxyHnrygOAtuk_OkzqmwPplQGfOKZPyGFWBo2xHPChysVX-VmRk81s3Qkza76Ty-tmVymcdTQ-59Eumq0bn7BH_X8mWEdr6NLGP5JOw7kjAGKBVJbHZ9fgUd72KDgFWiHOF-brEkXABL4IgeDqOhAuDP30bAyRFbtDWme5GPcnZU3t13qLDLEDPSK1jrl3X-OU8d2WOALBrnaJhmPw8z7H20Nx61vuio7KoCRPqD_3HT_Plga7dHT43DkQ
login_data[response][authorizationCode]: cf7d3de8d4c7f4277a128d2453423235.0.swxu.KmQXI352ayadDUh3cBGCjA
login_data[response][user]: 000674.6b053c49f8cc45b1bce5623f23343.1836
app_version: 1.0.1
timezone_offset: 120
```

login.ts function

```
async checkApple(login_data) {
    const loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      spinner: 'bubbles',
      //content: 'Loading...',
      //dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    loader.present();

    this.userData.appleLogin(login_data).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        loader.dismiss();
        if (data.success) {
          this.userData.setSession('HAS_LOGGED_IN', true);
          this.userData.setUserData(data.userData);
          this.router.navigate(["app/tablinks/home"]);
          //this.events.publish('user:signup');
          //this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage', {}, { animate: true, direction: 'forward' });
        }
        else {
         
        }
      },
        err => {
          loader.dismiss();
          
        })
    ).subscribe()
  }

  loginApple() {
    let options: SignInWithAppleOptions = {
      clientId: 'com.projectr.mobile',
      redirectURI: 'https://www.project.com/',
      scopes: 'email name',
      state: '12345',
      nonce: 'nonce',
    };
    
    SignInWithApple.authorize(options)
      .then((result: SignInWithAppleResponse) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.checkApple(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle error
      });




    (<any>window).cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.signin(
      { requestedScopes: [0, 1] },
      (succ) => {

        console.log('APPLE', JSON.stringify(succ));
        //why dont go to start page? ah ok where?there but it is under the tabs lol see the tabs?
        this.checkApple(succ);
        //succ.email
        //alert(JSON.stringify(succ))
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
      }
    )
  }
```

user-data.ts function

```
appleLogin(login_data) {
        let device = {};

        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            /*device = {
                platform: this.device.platform,
                uuid: this.device.uuid,
                cordova: this.device.cordova,
                model: this.device.model,
                manufacturer: this.device.manufacturer,
                version: this.device.version,
            };*/
        }

        var timezone_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
        timezone_offset = timezone_offset == 0 ? 0 : -timezone_offset;

        const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'sign_in_with_apple';
        const data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
            login_data: login_data,
            device: device,
            app_version: this.appData.APP_VERSION,
            timezone_offset: timezone_offset
        });

        return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options });
    };
```

sign_in_with_apple PHP FUNCTION

```
function sign_in_with_apple()
{
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $response['success'] = false;

    $loginData = $_POST['login_data'];
    $identityToken = $loginData['identityToken'];
    $clientUser = $loginData['user'];
    $clientAuthorizationCode = $loginData['authorizationCode'];

    $appleSignInPayload = ASDecoder::getAppleSignInPayload($identityToken);

    /**
     * Obtain the Sign In with Apple email and user creds.
     */
    $email = $appleSignInPayload->getEmail();//for username put givenname and family name all together without space
    $user = $appleSignInPayload->getUser();

    /**
     * Determine whether the client-provided user is valid.
     */
    $isValid = $appleSignInPayload->verifyUser($clientUser);

    if ($isValid) {
        // Check if email exists

        try
        { 

            $username = strstr($email, '@', true);

            $db = getDB();
            $sql = "SELECT uid,notification_created,username,name,profile_pic,tour,email, api_signature,first_name,last_name, artisticBehaviour,location,bio,friend_count
            FROM users WHERE (username=:username or email=:email) AND status='1' ";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $mainCount = $stmt->rowCount();
            $userData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $created = time();
            if ($mainCount == 0) {

                $api_signature = md5(time() . $username . rand(1, 1000));

                $status = '1';
                if (SMTP_CONNECTION > 0) {
                    $status = '0';
                }
                /*Inserting user values*/
                $email_active_code = $email . time();
                $sql1 = "INSERT INTO users(username,password,email,last_login,email_activation,status, api_signature)VALUES(:username,:password,:email,:created,:email_activation,:status,:api_signature)";
                $stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
                $stmt1->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $password = hash('sha256', $signupData['password']);
                $stmt1->bindParam("password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt1->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt1->bindParam("created", $created);
                $stmt1->bindParam("status", $status);
                $stmt1->bindParam("api_signature", $api_signature);
                $stmt1->bindParam("email_activation", $email_active_code);
                $stmt1->execute();

                $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT uid,notification_created,username,name,first_name,last_name, profile_pic,tour,email,friend_count FROM users WHERE username=:username");
                $stmt2->bindParam("username", $data->username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt2->execute();
                $userData = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $uid = $userData[0]->uid;



                $stmt3->bindParam("created", $time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $me = 'me';
                $stmt3->bindParam("me", $me, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt3->execute();

                $userData = internalUserDetails($email); // this one where isit?

               
                $response['success'] = true; // 2
                $response['userData'] = $userData;

            } else { // sign in
                $photos_query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM user_uploads WHERE uid_fk='$uid' and group_id_fk='0'");
                $photos_count = $photos_query->rowCount(); /* Photos Count */
                $updates_query = $db->query("SELECT msg_id FROM messages WHERE uid_fk='$uid' and group_id_fk='0'");
                $updates_count = $updates_query->rowCount(); /* Updates Count */
                $time = time();
                $updates_query = $db->query("UPDATE users SET last_login='$time',photos_count='$photos_count',updates_count='$updates_count' WHERE uid='$uid'");

                $userData->profile_pic = profilePic($userData->profile_pic);
                $userData->configurations = configurations();

                $response['success'] = true; // 2
                $response['userData'] = $userData;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text35":' . $e->getMessage() . '}}';
        }
    }
    else {
        $response['error'] = 'Please allow access to your email';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your network error block has -

```
Request Data
MIME Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
login_data[response][identityToken]: eyJraWQiOiJmaDZCczhDIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiY29tLnJvdmVzcGllci5tb2JpbGUiLCJleHAiOjE2NzUxNTY4MzQsImlhdCI6MTY3NTA3MDQzNCwic3ViIjoiMDAwNjc0LjZiMDUzYzSI6Im5vbmNlIiwiY19oYXNoIjoiZUY2WEdNRDhtYzViT3o0U0JVQnF5QSIsImVtYWlsIjoic2ltb25pb2FubmlkZXNAaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6InRydWUiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2NzUwNzA0MzQsIm5vbmNlX3N1cHBvcnRlZCI6dHJ1ZX0.bvXBlch8O-H690PsIFNZpJqauCcdozuZggt0I1nGY0PHQ075OSHKYlUXvsY_aOTIEzxyHnrygOAtuk_OkzqmwPplQGfOKZPyGFWBo2xHPChysVX-VmRk81s3Qkza76Ty-tmVymcdTQ-59Eumq0bn7BH_X8mWEdr6NLGP5JOw7kjAGKBVJbHZ9fgUd72KDgFWiHOF-brEkXABL4IgeDqOhAuDP30bAyRFbtDWme5GPcnZU3t13qLDLEDPSK1jrl3X-OU8d2WOALBrnaJhmPw8z7H20Nx61vuio7KoCRPqD_3HT_Plga7dHT43DkQ
login_data[response][authorizationCode]: cf7d3de8d4c7f4277a128d2453423235.0.swxu.KmQXI352ayadDUh3cBGCjA
login_data[response][user]: 000674.6b053c49f8cc45b1bce5623f23343.1836
app_version: 1.0.1
timezone_offset: 120
```

which shows another layer (response) in your login_data so you should be getting some array key errors in your PHP logs, before the fatal exception -

```
Warning: Undefined array key "identityToken" in ...
Warning: Undefined array key "user" in ...
Warning: Undefined array key "authorizationCode" in ...
```

You need to change the initial assignment of $login_data to -

```
$loginData = $_POST['login_data']['response'];
```

There may well be further errors after this.